# simple pig to join and process two bags

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following simple pig script,

```
AA = LOAD 'A' USING PigStorage(',') as (f1,f2,f3);
BB = LOAD 'B' AS (f1);
C = foreach AA generate f1;
C = JOIN AA BY f1 LEFT OUTER, BB BY f1 using 'replicated';
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN((IsEmpty(AA) ? null : AA));
store D into 'd';
```

but when I run, it gives me this error:

Invalid scalar projection: AA : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Could you please help?

Best,
Sara

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IsEmpty](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#isempty) documentation:

> ,,Checks if a bag or map is empty"

In your case it doesn't work since *C* is just one *outer bag* containing one tuple/line with fields from *AA* and *BB* :

```
C: {AA::f1: int,AA::f2: chararray,AA::f3: chararray,BB::f1: int}
```

You may apply the [Bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#arithmetic) operator on each field from *AA* instead to check and replace values, e.g:

```
D = foreach C generate (AA::f1 is null ? '-1' : AA::id) ... ;
```

But if you stick to IsEmpty, then the following will do the job:

```
D = foreach C {
 bg = TOBAG(TOTUPLE(AA::f1,AA::f2,AA::f3));
 generate IsEmpty(bg) ...;
}
```

Note:
I think there might be a typo in the Pig documentation at the IsEmpty section.
[Earlier](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#IsEmpty) in the example **cogroup** was used for joining the two relations which creates an inner bag on which IsEmpty can operate. [Later](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#isempty) this was replaced by left join which causes the same issue you described.